# Estimated marginal means for repeated measures ANOVA in r

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lsmeans

I am trying to extract estimated marginal means for a repeated measures ANOVA.
But I get a warning and can't /don't know how to extract the time factor.

```
Warning message:  
In ref_grid(object, ...) :  
  There are unevaluated constants in the response formula  
Auto-detection of the response transformation may be incorrect
```

Also:

```
Note: Use 'contrast(regrid(object), ...)' to obtain contrasts of back-
transformed estimates
```

**Sample data**

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

Df <- data.frame(
  score1 = runif(100, 1, 9),
  score2 = runif(100, 1, 9),
  gender = runif(100, 0, 1) %>% 
    round() %>% 
    dplyr::recode("0" = "Male", "1" = "Female") %>% 
    factor(levels = c("Male", "Female")),
  residence = runif(100, 0, 1) %>% 
    round() %>% 
    dplyr::recode("0" = "City", "1" = "Rural") %>% 
    factor(levels = c("City", "Rural"))
)
```

**The model**

```
fit <- lm(as.matrix(select(Df, score1, score2)) ~ 
            residence + gender + residence:gender,
          data = Df)

grid <- expand.grid(time = gl(2, 1))

rstatix::Anova(fit, idata = grid, idesign = ~time, type = "III")
summary(fit_anova, multivariate = FALSE, univariate = TRUE)

emmeans(fit, specs = pairwise ~ residence*gender)
```

I have tried to use lme4. Then I can extract the estimated marginal means, but with lmer I can't calculate the partial eta squared.

Comment: You say you get a warning, but you don't show what that warning is. Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added the warning.

Comment: What is happening is the complicated response in the model looks like it may be a transformation, but it can't figure it out. Add `, tran = NULL` to the `emmeans` call and it will fix it.

Comment: Okay, I do however still get the warning when adding `, tran = NULL`. Below the displayed  estimated means, I get "Results are averaged over the levels of: rep.meas 
Note: contrasts are still on the as.matrix.select scale". And the important part is, I can't see the results for time.

Comment: You *specified* you wanted means for residence*gender. So you got results for combinations of those two factors.    By default, the multivariate levels are named rep.meas. You can name it something else if you like, read the documentation for ref_grid. If you include rep.meas (or whatever name you give it) in your specs, you'll see results for it. If you don't, then you won't.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem. Adding "rep.meas" to the call gave me the results I was looking for.